# View design for a Django website which has a RESTful API from the get go

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to build a Django powered website. I want the website to be dynamic. For example, I want the profile page for a authenticated user to contain multiple resources (like a friends list, a group list, usage history etc) and these resources should be loaded in the same area on the page by making API calls without reloading the page.

Here is my understanding of the process:

1. Browser on the client side requests the profile page at www.example.com/user:id
2. The server returns a HTTP response and sends the html, css and javascript to the browser.
3. To load variable resources on the webpage, for example, the friend list, the javascript makes API calls using HTTP and sending context in JSON.
4. The API returns a JSON response which contain the data requested.
5. Javascript renders the data as html and the client is able to see new content on the same page.

I thought that in order to do this, some of my server side views need to be ordinary Django views which returns an HTTP response, while some others need to be API views which return JSON.

Now here's my confusion. Let's say **www.example.com/user:id** is processed using an ordinary django view, while **www.example.com/user/:id/friendslist** is processed using an API view. Now if the user inadvertently points the browser at **www.example.com/user/:id/friendslist** by typing the entire URL and hits go, what happens?

If I go with the flow of logic that I mentioned above, then the view will simply return a JSON. No html, css or javascript. In this case, how will the browser know what html to display?

I am just a beginner and I am sure I got the flow of logic wrong. Can someone please point out which part I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if the user inadvertently points the browser at www.example.com/user/:id/friendslist by typing the entire URL and hits go, what happens?

It depends on how you coded your server. In Django you can use [`is_ajax`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax) to check whether the request was AJAX or not. You *could* return an HTTP error code when the request is not an AJAX one, if you wanted. So a user who inadvertently points the browser to your URL but does not take any further action will get an error.

Note here that a knowledgeable user could circumvent `is_ajax` by setting the request header field `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` to `XMLHttpRequest` manually.

> If I go with the flow of logic that I mentioned above, then the view will simply return a JSON. No html, css or javascript. In this case, how will the browser know what html to display?

Setting your returned data type to `application/json` already tells the browser what it is dealing with. The least a browser would do this with this is display it as text.

Here's an example of an API call that returns JSON: https://api.zotero.org/users/475425/collections/9KH9TNSJ/items?format=json My browser just shows the JSON.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry I accepted it after such a long time. I thought I will receive an email when an answer is posted, so I did not check here. Sadly I received no email all this time and had no idea that you posted the answer.